# Executing parallel stages with declarative pipeline only using last item from list

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, since currently when i try to iterate on a list the creation of the stages seems fine, but when executing the shellscript, the value used is allways the last item of the list:

**Working pipeline:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('set servers') {
            steps {
                script {
                    my_list = ['server1','server-2','server-3']
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Execute then') {
            parallel {
                stage('shouter') {
                    steps {            
                        script {
                            shouter = [:]
                            script {
                                for(i in my_list) {
                                    shouter["${i}"] = {
                                        echo "standupandshout.sh ${i}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }                            
                            parallel shouter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Console Output:**

```
Replayed #4
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (set servers)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Execute then)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [shouter] { (Branch: shouter)
[Pipeline] [shouter] stage
[Pipeline] [shouter] { (shouter)
[Pipeline] [shouter] script
[Pipeline] [shouter] {
[Pipeline] [shouter] script
[Pipeline] [shouter] {
[Pipeline] [shouter] }
[Pipeline] [shouter] // script
[Pipeline] [shouter] parallel
[Pipeline] [server1] { (Branch: server1)
[Pipeline] [server-2] { (Branch: server-2)
[Pipeline] [server-3] { (Branch: server-3)
[Pipeline] [server1] echo
[server1] standupandshout.sh server-3
[Pipeline] [server1] }
[Pipeline] [server-2] echo
[server-2] standupandshout.sh server-3
[Pipeline] [server-2] }
[Pipeline] [server-3] echo
[server-3] standupandshout.sh server-3
[Pipeline] [server-3] }
[Pipeline] [shouter] // parallel
[Pipeline] [shouter] }
[Pipeline] [shouter] // script
[Pipeline] [shouter] }
[Pipeline] [shouter] // stage
[Pipeline] [shouter] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Desired output:**

```
[Pipeline] [server1] echo
[server1] standupandshout.sh server-1
[Pipeline] [server1] }
[Pipeline] [server-2] echo
[server-2] standupandshout.sh server-2
[Pipeline] [server-2] }
[Pipeline] [server-3] echo
[server-3] standupandshout.sh server-3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to groovy closures and when the code they contain gets evaluated.
http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/

> When the closures are run the value that is bound to the variable i is the value it had on the final iteration of the loop rather than the iteration where the closure was created. The closures' scopes have references to i and by the time any of the closures are executed i is 5.
>
> Variables local to the loop body do not behave like this, obviously because each closure scope contains a reference to a different variable

This is why your stage name is ok but your value is not.

> What’s the solution? Should we always use .each rather than a for loop? Well, I kind of like for loops in many cases and there can be memory utilization differences (don’t take that to mean loops are "better" or "more efficient").
>
> If you simply alias the loop variable and refer to that alias in the
>   closure body all will be well

```
def fns = []
for (i in (1..5)) {
    def myi = i
    def isq = i * i
    fns << {->
        println "$myi squared is $isq"
    }
}
fns.each { it() }
```

So this should work:

```
script {
  shouter = [:]
  for(i in my_list) {
    def val = i
    shouter["${i}"] = {
      echo "standupandshout.sh ${val}"
    }
  }
  parallel shouter
}
```